# i am unable find the class file in the jar

Tags: java, eclipse

Below is the code in eclipse,

```
public class MBILogin extends
com.sterlingcommerce.woodstock.ui.servlet.MBILogin
```

These are two different MBILogin from two different packages.

I am unable to find the second MBILogin class in the jar file. I have used a decompiler for illustration.

[image]

When I hover over it with my cursor, it shows an error error to the effect of "create MBILogin class in such and such a package" or "fix the project," but I'm able to build the project successfully and the application works as expected.

I am unable to discover where the MBILogin class (in that com.sterlingcommerce.woodstock.ui.servlet package) is coming from.

Please give any suggestions to find that class file.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse provides an easy way to track the project/library where a class is located on:

On a source code window, simply hover the name of the searched class while pressing CTRL. Then click on it, and let Eclipse open it on a new window (no matter if it shows just bytecode and no source code).

Then, you must click on the *Link with editor* button [image: link with editor] of the *project explorer* view: This will show the library/project where the class in active editor window is located.